# Extract coordinate system,projection names for files listed in a csv using gdal/python

Tags: qgis, gdal, pyqgis

We have 1000's of files for which projection/datum/geocs/projcs names has to be extracted. This code reads the filename listed in the csv.

```
from os import path
from osgeo import gdal,osr
import csv
csvpath = r"D:\\Test\\QGISPRJ.csv"
csvdir = path.split(csvpath)[0]
with open(csvpath, "r") as csvfile:
    fcs = [r[0] for r in csv.reader(csvfile)]
    for ds in fcs:
        print ds

Output:
E:\Santiago_Low\SourceData\Chile Projects\spectrem\Area2\Area2_AEM_x7.TIF
E:\Santiago_Low\SourceData\_South America Regional\233_080_Si_15m_321comp.ECW
E:\Santiago_Low\SourceData\Inactive Projects\ASTER_VNIR_orthoRGB_PSAD56_19S.TIF
E:\Santiago_Low_Priority\SourceData\Chile Projects\Explora_KRIP_Res.TIF
```

But, if i use getProjection() in the code - as mentioned in this thread - [GDAL/Python: How do I get coordinate system name from SpatialReference?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/60371/gdal-python-how-do-i-get-coordinate-system-name-from-spatialreference) - i am getting this error

```
from os import path
from osgeo import gdal,osr
import csv
csvpath = r"D:\\Test\\QGISPRJ.csv"
csvdir = path.split(csvpath)[0]
with open(csvpath, "r") as csvfile:
    fcs = [r[0] for r in csv.reader(csvfile)]
    for ds in fcs:
        prj=ds.GetProjection()
        srs=osr.SpatialReference(wkt=prj)
        print srs.GetAttrValue('projcs')
        print srs.GetAttrValue('geogcs')
        print srs.GetAttrValue('Datum')
        print srs.GetAttrValue('Projection')

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<input>", line 4, in <module>
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'GetProjection'
```

But if i run the same code without the csv file as an input and use the filename directly it works fine.

```
from osgeo import gdal,osr
ds=gdal.Open(r'E:\\Santiago_Low\\SourceData\\Chile Projects\\Ground POS EM\\Mapinfo\\300mSlice_Image.TIF')
prj=ds.GetProjection()
print prj
srs=osr.SpatialReference(wkt=prj)
print srs.GetAttrValue('projcs')
print srs.GetAttrValue('geogcs')
```

Since i am very much a beginner as far as Python is concerned, i don't know how to proceed.I've read this [gdal/python: extracting projection info from hdf file](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/168910/gdal-python-extracting-projection-info-from-hdf-file/168950) and few other questions w.r.t ***'str' object has no attribute error*** in python. But still couldn't able to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: `ds` is a string. You probably mean to open a dataset, i.e. `for fname in fcs: ds = gdal.Open(fname)` ...

Comment: Should be closed... not likely to be helpful to anyone else. Simple mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The attribute error is because `ds` is a string, and not a GDAL dataset.

It can be fixed by referencing the file name string in the `for` loop, then opening the dataset:

```
for fname in fcs:
    ds = gdal.Open(fname)
```