# How to extract data from DAAC index

Tags: python, usgs, nasa

I would like to extract a MODIS land cover dataset, among other things from DAAC. I found [this python tool](https://git.earthdata.nasa.gov/projects/LPDUR/repos/daac_data_download_python/browse) which allows me to feed a URL and automatically download the file, and also [this library](https://hdfeos.org/software/pyhdf.php) which allows opening hdf datasets. I aim to later [convert hdf datasets extracted from DAAC with gdal or some other python tool.](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/168910/gdal-python-extracting-projection-info-from-hdf-file)

However, I have a problem. I have no idea what the [index of the DAAC database](https://e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov) is showing. I see the following abbreviations at the index but have no idea what they mean, and which one of them can lead me to the dataset I want.

- ASTT
- COMMUNITY
- ECOSTRESS
- MEASURES
- MOLA
- MOLT
- MOTA
- VIIRS

Could anyone help me navigate through the DAAC database to get to what I want? Is there a document somewhere that can explain what these things mean?

Comment: Why close? Do you have any suggestions for improving the question? Close should be a last resort...

Comment: MODIS datasets are so huge and the naming of products is really confusing. I found this site, which lists modis products and explains even the abbreviations of the data pool: https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/products/mcd12q1v006/ (an example product) and the link to the data pool: https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/tools/data-pool/